# C# - String stored as Base64, but the retreived string is not a valid base64 string

Tags: c#, base64

I'm using Base64 encoding to store values from my data structure into a string. 
Basically what I do is convert a byte array into base64 string

```
string StoredData = Convert.ToBase64String(ByteArray);
```

I then divide StoredData into strings of a maximum length of 256 Characters and store them as an ASCII string (in AutoCAD XData as an `DxfCode.ExtendedDataAsciiString`) .

When I want to retrieve my data I do the following:

First I combine each 256 long string using `StoredData = sting1 + string2 + ...`
Then I convert StoredData back into ByteArray using

```
var ByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(StoredData);
```

Now this has worked great for me and my clients until a month ago, where one of my clients has had some crash and errors popping up.
I asked him to send me his stored data, and I got surprised to see that his data contained invalid Base64 Characters (see sample below)

> tM7x24QLLLALr5ivAx3XFAM7uciYXrCjKXSFd3XOL/KGIc3C+JMO8QjHT/4c+puYrNLq5r9Is0vpDKyuxw9I6R3f1LuOYSdHS6XgZJEyMvGwSHNRSYJ/a0IoumQftB3XspQRwp4QSd7qcUVsrXw0+2RS/sd2vAvUFxEQgwsHaabb01YjchGeyxr1f78A4qy2BL/oHAsRak9UYN0mDzhZgbhpahlgdK3eWd8b2BTM01lWh74pYUrJR+JfQ0tw0Eu㿔
>
> Z/1JxBMUv2cB6NrFehSuNF9l4dhAaZQ+TcIClZmk/ZC8TJ0rKka/J+HqhLDAwWExB3nXoIi00uJnE7J4R6rU+Q==

as you can see the first 256 long string had an invalid Base64 character (㿔)

Why is that happening? can this be related to the users computer? I tried to replicate this error without any success and because I don't have access to their computers, I'm starting to think it might be something on their side.

The application uses .Net framework version 4.5.

Edit: it turned out client has sent me a recovered document which didn't recover the text strings properly which explains the corrupted string.

Comment: Impossible to guess when the only code you've shown us is two calls to framework methods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what's in between is just saving StoredData into AutoCAD and retrieving it back when needed. And I can see the stored value in both when I debug or from inside AutoCAD and they are working correctly. So basically I open a Transaction in AutoCAD, put the strings into a ResultBuffer under a custom and unique app name then I commit the changes.

Comment: Im wondering since you are splitting up the ASCII and using "+" to format a string if you are hitting some side effect that its converting it into Chinese Unicode. I dont know if this helps but the unicode for that character is U+3FD4

Comment: "what's in between is ..." - a whole lot of code you've written and/or interaction with the AutoCAD API. Do you really believe that the problem location is more likely to be in a) .NET Framework Code, b) AutoCAD code, or c) your code? If your answer is (a) or (b), you need to present serious evidence for why it should be so. I would guess that `ToBase64String` and `FromBase64String` are used billions of times a day.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I wasn't sure if there is a chance for that conversion to fail in some circumstances. Now that I know it can't fail, I would just eliminate that possibility and look somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the app has crashed and client has recovered the drawing document with corrupted string.